# PHP generate sql where clause from array

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create dinamically in my php class a where clause from a array where are defined search fields.

```
$search = array('brand' => 'something', 'model' => 'something');
$myclass->testarr($search);
```

CLASS

```
public function testarr($search){

    if (!empty($search)){

        foreach ($search as $key => $value) {

            $where = $key . " = " . $value;
        }

    $clause = !empty($where) ? 'WHERE' : '';

    $result = $this->db->mysqli->query
    ("SELECT * FROM tb1 $clause $where");

    }

}
```

My problem is to manage a clause with more than one field by entering the suffix AND. How could I do that? Thanks

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param is a better option

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advice to do this:

```
$where = array();
if (!empty($search) && is_array($search)) {
    foreach ($search as $key => $value) {
        $where[] = $key . " = " . $value;
    }
}
if (!empty($where))
    $query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE %s', implode('AND ', $where));
else
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tb1';
```

Using `implode` makes things easier.

Beware however of escaping issues, as your code is prone to security issues.

Comment: Clean, but $where may be empty, and "WHERE" should be removed

Comment: No one should use this insecure/unstable answer.  A properly implemented prepared statement is called for.

Answer (score 1):

There is one flaw with your code: `$where = $key . " = " . $value;` will overwrite `$where` in each iteration, you need to use `.=` to concatenate. Then this could be done e.g. the following way

```
$where = "";
foreach ($search as $key=>$value) {
    if (!empty($where)) $where .= " AND ";
    $where .= $key . " = " . $value;
}
$clause = !empty($where) ? 'WHERE '.$where : '';
```

This will add a `AND` before every condition, starting from the second (because for the first the if will fail).

I suggest researching [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), these will make your code alot more secure and once you understood the concept, they become quite easy to handle (imo). Because if that is most of your code at the moment, you are quite vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: I thank you for your solution. Can you tell me how to do it with prepared statements? Thanks

Comment: Well okay, this code wouldn't be much simpler, as you'd have to iterate twice over `$search` (once for keys and once for values) - I think _Michaël Perrin_ is quite elegant

Comment: No one should use the insecure/unstable snippet.  A properly implemented prepared statement is called for.